# Cómo configurar el .env de Laravel 5.4 para correr el comando php artisan migrate a la BD mySQL de Hometead?

Tags: mysql, laravel, vagrant, base-de-datos

La conexión estoy seguro que se realiza, porque puedo ejecutar correctamente el comando `php artisan migrate:refresh`, pero no puedo hacer consultas desde el ORM.

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=33060
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret`
```

**Si cambio la configuración a ésta:**

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=33060
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret`
```

Me deja conectarme a la BD, pero no me deja correr el comando: `php artisan migrate:refresh`. Todos los comandos los hago desde mi máquina local, no desde el ssh del Homestead.

Comment: ¿Y qué error te da?

Comment: En el primer caso, al intentar conectarme a la base de datos, sale el error: 

PDOException in Connector.php line 55:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

En el segundo caso al ejecutar el comando ´php artisan migrate:refresh´ me arroja el error: "[PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"

Comment: ¿@JuanArias ya abriste la configuración de `homestead` para registrar su proyecto ? ¿desde donde está ejecutando el comando ? recuerde que debe hacerlo desde `ssh` :D

Comment: @Dev.Joel Sí, está registrado, y corre bien con DB_HOST=localhost, pero no me deja ejecutar comandos del Artisan con la BD. Y si la cambio por DB_HOST=127.0.0.1, no se conecta, pero sí me deja hacer los comandos del artisan. El comando lo ejecuto para ambos casos desde mi máquina local. La idea es no tocar el ssh del Homestead.

Comment: @JuanArias los comandos relacionados con la base de datos, debe hacerlo desde  la máquina virtual de homestead. creo que ese es su principal problema.

Comment: El archivo `.env` no se guarda en el caché de `Laravel`, si tu lo editas no habrá cambios en `Laravel` a menos que ejecutes el comando `config:cache`, pruébalo a ver si tu código funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Tienes que comprobar el puerto (que será el correcto), el nombre de la base de datos, el nombre de usuario y la contraseña.
Yo uso Xampp y lo tengo en el puerto 3306. Por defecto (si no los has tocado), el nombre de usuario es root y la contraseña dejala vacía.
Ten en cuenta que yo no uso Homestead y cualquier cosa puede cambiar en XAMPP.
Espero que te sirva.

Answer (score 0):

[2024/MARZO]

Tuve el mismo problema con la ejecución de Laravel en Docker para Mac, lo he resuelto cambiando la dirección `127.0.0.1` por la dirección ip local de mi equipo `192.168.1.X`, con esto tanto `php artisan migrate:refresh` funciona, así como la ejecución de codigo en los archivos php:
`$frutas = DB::table('frutas')->get();`

Espero que la respuesta le sirva a las siguientes personas que tengan el mismo problema.